# How to Prevent Brute Force Attack on WordPress

Tags: login, security

my site went down for 1hr. and after then continuously. So I asked my hosting what the problem is with my website. they say I am in under brute force attack. told me to hire someone.

I Limit Login Attempts by using a WordPress plugin. I want to know what other solutions I need to do

Answer (score 1):

To prevent brute force attacks, there are some security measures you need to implement on your site

1. Prevent the discovery of usernames
2. **Limit login attempts**
3. **Change the default login page URL**
4. Implement two-factor authentication
5. **Implement HTTP authentication**
6. **Use a firewall**
7. Implement Geoblocking

If you use a username and password that’s long and unique, it will be difficult for hackers bots to guess your credentials. dont use Admin as a User name (password - Tfs7H2B9$J#d)

**Prevent Discovery of Username**

- Change Display Name
- Use Plugin to Prevent Rest API From Displaying Usernames

[image]

**Change Default Login Page URL**

- Install and activate WPS Hide Login on your WordPress website
- set the new login URL - example.com/wp.dd-login

[image]

**Implement HTTP authentication. (Best and Final One)**

- You can add another layer of protection on your WordPress login page
  through HTTP authentication

[image]

- When you open a login page of a website with HTTP authentication
  installed, a sign-in box appears on the top of the page asking for
  your credentials.
- Without these credentials no one can access the login page.
- Install and activate HTTP Auth wordpress plugin on your WordPress
  website.
- On your WordPress dashboard, you should be able to see the HTTP Auth
  option on the left side of the screen. Select HTTP Auth > Settings.
- Choose a Username and Password and Save it.

All Images Credits and Content Credits goes to [Prevent WordPress Brute Force Attacks](https://trendyport.com/how-to-protect-your-website-from-wordpress-brute-force-attacks/)

Comment: I did everything you said. Let's see what happens. Thank you very much.